# Visual Studio Templates

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, templates, download

I currently have Visual Studio 2010 Express Visual Basic. I was wondering if there was anyway I could download the C# tmeplate online without having to download Visual Studio 2010 C# Express. I have tried searching on the online templates and I could not find it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Go to File - new project- this will give you this window.

[image: new file vs]

Then click on online templates.

[This link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms185306%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) tells you how to find and install templates.

[Article on](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/6db0hwky%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) Visual Studio 2010 templates.

Here is [another link](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/60cb1c63-0132-471f-b0fc-0b2687c44e0a/install-service-template-wcf-on-visual-studio-express-2010) to the MSDN forums, where are question is asked about installing template on VS 2010 Express, you may find it useful.